# Python to use shell from sdk

Tags: python, shell, sdk

I am trying to execute a few shell commands from python. I was able to do that with 'os' functions. But, the default shell `/bin/sh` is used for execution. I need the shell to be used from my sdk.

I tried setting the `os.environ['SHELL'] = '${base_prefix}/bin/sh'` where is `base_prefix` is path. But still the required shell is not used. Instead of `/bin/sh` the `/usr/bin/env` is used. Can anyone know how this can be resolved.

FYI... below is code snippet of my application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys
os.unsetenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
os.environ['SHELL'] = '${base_prefix}/bin/sh'
os.execlp($CC, $@)
```

Comment: can't you run directly `'${base_prefix}/bin/sh -c "your_command"` ? Some command may also get shell as parameter - `subprocess.run(..., shell='${base_prefix}/bin/sh')`

Comment: all this may need to put correct value in place `${base_prefix}` before running python function because it may not replace it automatically

Comment: try `'${base_prefix}/bin/sh -c "your_command"` in any command which you use.

Comment: I checked documentation for `subprocess` and it has to be `executable="/path/to/shell`  - like `subprocess.run('ls', executable='/bin/fish', shell=True)`